# Как вытащить ровно перевод слова?

Tags: python, json, requests, яндекс-переводчик

Имеем примерный код на Python:

```
import requests
token = 'токен'
url_trans = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate'
text_translet = "hello"
trans_option = {'key':token, 'lang':'en-ru', 'text': text_translet} #устанавливаем параментры перевода 
webRequest = requests.get(url_trans, params = trans_option) #отправляем запрос
print(webRequest["text"])
```

Далее получаем ошибкой по голове. Если написать `print(webRequest)`, то мы получим много лишней информации. Вопрос: как вытащить ровно перевод слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете распарсить ответ как `JSON` с помощью одноимённого метода.

***Пример:***

```py
response = requests.get(url_trans, params = trans_option).json()
print(response['text'][0])
```

***stdout:***

```py
привет
```